# How many low-power batteries to power up 12V LEDs?

Tags: led-strip

I bought some strips of 12V LEDs and it comes with a pack of 10 x 1.5V batteries. The whole pack gives ±14.88V, which I thought to be quite high. Is this normal? Does this reduce the life of the LED strip?

Also, if I'm using rechargeable Ni-MH (1.2V) batteries instead of the pack that comes with the LED stip, how many do I need?

Thank you.

Comment: If they are White LEDs Vled ~= 3.2V -3.5V typically. 3 are placed in series with a resistor so VLEds = 9.6V - 10.5V typically. VLED varies with current and batch and device. Balance of voltage is dropped across Rser = series R. If they spec at say 13V and if say Vled avg = 3.3V then VLEDS = 9.9V so Vr = (13-9.9) = 3.1V. Nominal rated current flows when Vr = 3.1V. So I_wrt_nominal ~~~~~= (Vin-9.9V)/3.1 x Irated. So at say 15V I = (15-9.9)/3.1 Irated = 5.1/3.1 Ir ~= 1.6 x Irated. As I rises VLED also rises so actual I will be lower than shown. eg If VLED rises to 3.5V then VLEDS ...

Comment: ... = 10.5V and I = (15-10.5)/3.1 = 4.5/3.1 x Ir ~= 1.45 x Irated. | And at saya Vin = 11V I = (11-9.9)/3.1 x Irated = 1.1/3.1 x Ir ~= 0.35 x I rated. Again, VLED changes as I changes so here Vled may be say 3V so Vleds = 9V so I is now (11-9)/3.1 Ir  = 2/3.1 Ir = 0.65 Irated. | **SO** IF strip is rated at say 13V as above current MAY be about 2/3 rated value at 11V in and ABOUT 50% above Irated at 15V in. For a modern phosphor LED 150% is too high - about 120% is typical allowed abs max. A responsible manufacturer will arrange current so about 120% of rated current flows when  ...

Comment: ... Vin is at abs max value liable to be experienced. A typical manufacturer won't. Alas. Manufacturers of lower end products know that buyers equate bright with good and push I up. | If you care you can add a constant current source. An LM317 does this well but needs 2V+ drop to operate. The two transistor cct that is often suggested is usually "not nice" but here may be OK. Vdrop min is probably around 1V so it makes the brightness noticeably lower at Vin low but saves your LEDs at Vin high. For max range at constant current a cheap transistor (bipolar or FET) + an opamp section can ...

Comment: ... do well. An eg LM324 gives 4 x opamps in a cheap pkg (< $1 in 1 in US retail, about 5c in volume in Asia). If interested ask about opamp and constant current circuits.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet for the strips? It's possible there is a voltage regulator on board. There could be a voltage tolerance that results in safe operation. It depends on the circuit that is on the strip. It's hard to say without more information.

Comment: Short answer, these strip are multiple parallel strips of 3 series leds plus 1 resistor, giving ~19mA @ 12v. Typically ~10~14V will work fine, with less or more current, respectfully.

Comment: **NOTE**: I posted this question here as I could not find any other "more suitable" StackExchange stie for it.

Answer (score 2):

Y'all feel free to tidy.
I may come back to it.
Content should be OK.
Rushing.

If they are White LEDs Vled ~= 3.2V -3.5V typically.
3 are placed in series with a resistor so VLEds = 9.6V - 10.5V typically.
VLED varies with current and batch and device.
Balance of voltage is dropped across Rser = series R.
If they spec at say 13V and if say Vled avg = 3.3V then VLEDS = 9.9V
so Vr = (13-9.9) = 3.1V.
Nominal rated current flows when Vr = 3.1V.
So I_wrt_nominal ~~~~~= (Vin-9.9V)/3.1 x Irated.
So at say 15V I = (15-9.9)/3.1 Irated
= 5.1/3 Ir ~= 1.6 x Irated.

As I rises VLED also rises so actual I will be lower than shown.
eg If VLED rises to 3.5V then VLEDS
= 10.5V and
I = (15-10.5)/3.1 = 4.5/3.1 x Ir ~= 1.45 x Irated.

And at say Vin = 11V
I = (11-9.9)/3.1 x Irated
= 1.1/3.1 x Ir ~= 0.35 x I rated.

Again, VLED changes as I changes so here Vled may be say 3V so Vleds = 9V so I is now
(11-9)/3.1 Ir = 2/3.1 Ir = 0.65 Irated.

SO IF strip is rated at say 13V as above current MAY be about 2/3 rated value at 11V in and ABOUT 50% above Irated at 15V in.

For a modern phosphor LED 150% is too high - about 120% is typical allowed abs max.
A responsible manufacturer will arrange current so about 120% of rated current flows when Vin is at abs max value liable to be experienced.

A typical manufacturer won't.
Alas.

Manufacturers of lower end products know that buyers equate bright with good and push I up.

If you care you can add a constant current source.
An LM317 does this well but needs 2V+ drop to operate.
The two transistor cct that is often suggested is usually "not nice" but here may be OK.   Vdrop min is probably around 1V so it makes the brightness noticeably lower at Vin low but saves your LEDs at Vin high.

For max range at constant current a cheap transistor (bipolar or FET) + an opamp section can do well.
An eg LM324 gives 4 x opamps in a cheap pkg (< $1 in 1 in US retail, about 5c in volume in Asia).
If interested ask about opamp and constant current circuits.

Answer (score 1):

Cells in series sum their voltages, thus 10 x 1.5V would equal 15V. Ten Ni-MH cells at 1.2V would be 12V.

The reason you measure 14.88V rather than 15V is because batteries (cells) are not ideal voltage sources, and have internal resistance as well as chemistry breakdown. With time, the voltage will drop more, and at some point the LEDs will fail to light (then it's time to replace or recharge the batteries).

Without knowing what LED strips you have specifically, there's no way to know what the tolerances are for supply voltage, whether it has any voltage regulation, or overvoltage protection. If the LED strip it not designed to be supplied with >12V, then yes, providing anything over the rated voltage may be driving them with too much current, and they will exhibit failures earlier.

The Ni-MH cells at 12V will likely power the strip just fine, but as they discharge, the LEDs will fail to light at the same point where the supply voltage is no longer sufficient.

Comment: Some of the strips are like [these](http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/automotive/automotive-lighting-bulbs/neon-led-automotive-lights/pilot-12-in-led-flex-lighting-strip-0416218p.html?utm_campaign=bazaarvoice&utm_medium=SearchVoice&utm_source=RatingsAndReviews&utm_content=Default#.U0xrTXUojH4). I don't have the package, so I can't give anymore information. (BTW: I know about the reason of 10 x 1.5V = 14.88V; I just thought it was useful to the question.) So, if the strips comes with such power source... what does it mean? Can I power them with a 15V source (i.e. 12 x 1.2V batteries)?

Comment: @YanickRochon They are probably 12V LEDs, but that doesn't mean they always use 12V, and it also doesn't mean anything about what kind of voltage supply you give them above 12V. You could give them 50V - just be sure to use a current limiting resistor (easiest, but not stable under supply voltage drop due to batteries getting low etc.) or some kind of constant current source (much better idea, doesn't matter what input voltage is as long as it's >12V). LEDs need a certain amount of voltage to start turning on, and from then on they draw current based on their charactistic curve.

Comment: @YanickRochon so at 12V they will draw their "test current" if you had access to a datasheet. At maybe 12.5 - 13.5V they will be drawing probably at their maximum rated current (bad), and above 14V they will be pulling many Amps and will quickly fail. One thing to notice is that 10x 1.5V batteries in series have very poor current sourcing ability, so the batteries themselves will actually (poorly) limit the current output, so it may be okay. If they were Lipo, or a car battery (100's of Amps source ability) then you would have an issue without a resistor.

Answer (score 1):

If the strips are made for automotive applications, as it appears from your link, they are probably designed to run of of the car's 12V (nominal) power rail.  This rail is actually around 13.5V when the engine is running.  It can surge higher when the engine is cranking, or even when you rev the engine.

So, if you want a non-automobile power source, I would target anywhere between 12V and 13.5V.  Call it 9 alkalines or 11 NiMHs.  I expect you can get away with 15V, but I would stay safe unless I needed the extra brightness :)

Good luck!

Comment: So, they provide a 15V power source, just for the show... sneaky marketing :)

Comment: @YanickRochon Ha! Yeah, could be. To give them the benefit of the doubt, maybe they spec'd the current limiting to handle a constant 15V input.  I had some auto LED arrays that I took apart, and they just used a simple resistor (a big, 20W resistor!) to limit the current.  If you drove it too high, it got brighter, and presumably burned out faster :)